# Create pandas DataFrame iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating the list as follows:

```
myList = []
for i in range(0,10):
    val0 = 1  # some formula for obtaining values
    val1 = 2.5
    val2 = 1.8
    myList.append([val0,val1,val2])
```

How can I do the same loop for pandas DataFrame (i.e. `myList` must be a `DataFrame`).

Comment: [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.concat.html) if you really need to, but it's better to do all the concatenation in a list as pandas has O(n) insertion).

Comment: @Alex: Could you please give an example relevant to my particular case?

Comment: Are the other answers clear?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ideally you want to create your `DataFrame` once you have all the data in place.  Slightly modifying your example:

```
my_df = []
for i in range(0,10):
    d = {
        'val0' : 1,  # some formula for obtaining values
        'val1' : 2.5,
        'val2' : 1.8
    }
    my_df.append(d)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)
```

So now `my_df` is a `DataFrame` with `val0`, `val1` and `val2` as columns

Comment: Shouldn't there be commas at the end of each of the dictionary elements?

Comment: @HeathRaftery there's no reason to enforce that,  I took this data from the OP's question.  Don't think I'm qualified to add my own comments to his/her data

Comment: The OP had them as statements in a loop. You have them as items in a dictionary. AFAIK, items have to be separated by commas when creating a dictionary using that syntax. I'm not widely experienced enough to know if there are exceptions, but all the versions of Python I have at hand report a syntax error when running your code. I had to change it to `d = { 'val0' : 1, 'val1' : 2.5, 'val2' : 1.8 }`.

Comment: I apologize, I totally misread your initial comment (I read "commas" as "comments").  You are correct about the syntax.  Will adjust the answer

Comment: This is very memory inefficient, and infeasible when the data is more than half your available memory. My only thought is to store in an easy file format (eg: csv) and read that directly as a DataFrame..

Answer (score 5):

if i got your question right:

```
import pandas as pd

myList = []

for i in range(0,10):
    val0 = 1  # some formula for obtaining values
    val1 = 2.5
    val2 = 1.8
    myList.append([val0,val1,val2])

df = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['val0','val1','val2'])
print(df)
```

PS you don't want to do append data to the DataFrame in the loop - it won't be very efficient.

Output:

```
   val0  val1  val2
0     1   2.5   1.8
1     1   2.5   1.8
2     1   2.5   1.8
3     1   2.5   1.8
4     1   2.5   1.8
5     1   2.5   1.8
6     1   2.5   1.8
7     1   2.5   1.8
8     1   2.5   1.8
9     1   2.5   1.8
```